# javascript display and hide div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I am new to Javascript, and I currently have an article that is being fetched from database, the article has two rows. **title** & **content** there are about 100 of these in my database. Now the objective is to list all the titles first, and when a user clicks on a title, to make the the relevant content appear underneath it. I can do this however this way.

```
<?php
//mysql query here...
foreach($result as $row) { ?>
<div id='title'> <?= $row['title'] ?> </div>
<div id='<?= $row['id'] ?>' style='display:none' 
             onclick=showContent(<?= $row['id'] ?>) > <?= $row['content'] ?> 
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The javascript to hide the show the content is this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function showContent(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='inline';
}
</script>
```

The `showContent()` function hides the div based on the id passed through the paramenter. 
But, the only problem is that, I need other previously displayed divs to truntate when a new one opens.

Meaning, the content should be visible only once, then when you click on another title, the previously opened content should disappear and only the new content should appear.

I hope that made sense. as I am lacking the grammar to explain it all. I tried to give small example here, which for some reason does not seem to work at all, but does in my localhost http://jsfiddle.net/YL6aH/

---

EDITED:

My full PHP loop, together will all the js/html

```
    <?php 
            $articlesForPreview = $createQuery
                ->query("SELECT * FROM timeline");              
                $fetchAll = $articlesForPreview->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
                foreach($fetchAll as $row) {?>
                <div id='timeline_container'>
                <span class='timeline_date'> <?= $row['time'] ?></span>
                <span class='timeline_title'> <a href='#' onclick=timeline(<?= $row['id'] ?>)><?= $row['title'] ?></a></span>
                <p id='<?= $row['id'] ?>' style='display:none;'> <?= $row['event'] ?></a></span>
            </div>

            <?php }?>



    </aside>
</section>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function timeline(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='inline';
}
</script>

<footer id='footer_container'>
```

Comment: do you have jQuery in your page

Comment: working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mvNtN/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny no. I don't. I am trying to use only javascript, but if someone can offer jQuery solution it's fine

Comment: Is your for loop generating `<div id='title'>` repeatedly? IDs **must** be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks I saw that. But, I have like 100 titles & content. So, when I click on a second title, I want the first one to disappear. That is the problem here

Comment: @j08691 my loop is generating `$row['id']` So, every id name is unique. But they are all numbers

Comment: Not according to what you posted above. `<div id='title'>` is within your loop.

Comment: @j08691 That was just an example. I have added all the codes in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remember the last item that is visible:

```
var active;
function showContent(id){
    if (active) active.style.display = 'none'; // hide previously visible element
    active = document.getElementById(id);    // keep track of the element you are about to show
    active.style.display='inline'; // show the new element
}
```

Keep in mind that this solution starts with no items visible and after that only allows one item to be visible at a time.

Comment: thanks. @Tibos. Just out of curiosity, if I wanted to lag the time it takes to show the content, how could I achieve it?  I was thinking about using a loop and sliding down by pixel but not sure if that is how anyone would do it.

Comment: If you want to simply show it later, you can use setTimeout. If you want to show it with an animation, then you have the "old" way of using setInterval and gradually changing a property such as opacity. The newer(better) way is similar, but uses window.requestAnimationFrame. Most people would abstract the details using a library like jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```
function showContent(id){
    $('.active').hide().removeClass('active');
    $('#'+id).show().addClass('active');
}
```

I see also that you will have multiple elements with `id=title`, you **must** change it to make every elem unique.

Comment: Tagged jQuery and say yes to a jQuery answer in the comments

Comment: I am guessing this is a jQuery implementation. But, what do the `active` and `.active` mean? are they classes for the content?

Comment: Yeah, `.active` is to target elements with this class

Answer (score 1):

You can go through all elements with an onclick of "showContent", hide them all, afterwards you can just show the one you want.

```
function showContent(id){
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for ( var i = 0; i<allElements.length; i++ ) {    
        if ( (allElements[i].onclick + "").indexOf("showContent") >= 0) {
            allElements[i].style.display = "none";       
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='inline';
}
```

Comment: I had this approach in my mind, but it seems a lot of task (performance & efficiency wise) to loop through all existing elements on every click.

Comment: The easier method would be to add a class to each of the elements which are going to be hidden/shown, then you can run a selector on that class only to do the hiding.  I just wanted to give you code that would work with what you had already.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to javascript and jquery myself, but one of the things we just did in the class I'm taking was the accordion display, where you attach event handlers in the document.ready for the click events for the header objects, and their div children elements, and it was done by swapping the css classes on the click events... are you using css?  in our version, anytime we clicked on a plus, it would expand the display to display the divs below, and clicking the minus pic it would close them... ours did it for all of them, but you should be able to code that even to "close" all of those displays, and then open/display only the divs that are children for the item clicked... is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeas, something like that. If there is anyway, I can minimize the use of JavaScript through the implementation of CSS, I would consider it. @Tibos has given me a working example, but simply trying to find a better alternative now (if any)

Comment: I would definitely use CSS.  It would be very simple, just create a class with a display:none;, and a second without... and then as you create the div's, add the none class to them.  Then every click event can just grab all that are in the displayed class, remove it, add the display none class, then remove and add the other class to the one you want displayed.  Between jquery and css, I would guess this would be the best and simplest approach.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. But, I am a CSS3 noob so, I can't do this now. Tibos's answer worked perfectly though. You should give it a look